# ViewPager2 is not able to get the current visible item view holder correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

So just to elaborate on the problem. I am trying to auto scroll to the next item after a certain interval. If i swipe manually the viewpager2 retrieves the itemview correctly. But when i do it in auto mode .It is not able to get the current visible item. Can someone help me in spotting the bug

```
 override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                val view =
                    (viewPager[0] as RecyclerView).layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position)
                view?.findViewById<LottieAnimationView>(R.id.iv)
                    ?.playAnimation()
             
                }
            }
```

And giving me null view. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Why you don't use viewPager2.getCurrentItem() ?

Comment: Hi! I just faced same issue, did you fix that?